# Graphics glitches in VirtualBox Ubuntu guest when 3D acceleration is enabled

Tags: drivers, virtualbox, virtualization, guest-additions, guest-os

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as a VirtualBox guest on a Windows 10 host machine, I've installed and re-installed guest additions by following the instruction on [this page](https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/3d-acceleration-for-ubuntu-guests-v2). The drivers appear to be configured fine.
`/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` gives:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Chromium 1.9

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Screenshots of some of the glitches:

[image: Logon window after suspend]

[image: Search]

[image: Taskbar]

[image: Launcher]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have the exact same glitches and still haven't found a solution.
Has anybody an idea of why 3D-acceleration causes this issue?
Turning 3D acceleration off works and all glitches disappear, but that is just a workaround.